# Comparing two numbers without comparison operators in verilog

Tags: verilog, comparison-operators, mux

Two 8-bit inputs are fed to the comparator, and if first one is greater than second, they are supposed to be subtracted, else they are supposed to be added. But, > and < operators aren't supposed to be used to compare them.
So, I have written my logic as:

```
input[7:0] in1,in2;
output select;
assign select=(in1-in2)?0:1;
```

It is always subtracting, unless difference equals 0. If I use division, 0 cannot be an input or my program can crash. Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that  the leftmost bit of a negative number is aways 1. So you can use it to check the sign of the difference.

```
input[7:0] in1,in2;
output select;
wire [7:0] difference = in1-in2;
wire sign_of_difference = difference[7];
assign select = sign_of_difference? 0:1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Alper. But, why did this work and the logic I used didn't? Does the wire or size match make any difference ?

Comment: You're welcome ZealousCoder. In `assign select=(in1-in2)?0:1;` , `in1-in2` is an 8-bit value. `(in1-in2)?` operation compares if the result this 8-bit subtraction is larger than zero or not, and returns 0 only if  `in1-in2` is zero. Please remember to accept the answer if you think it solves your problem.